Mounted lifecycle hook - difference between Vue 3 and Vue 2
my company migrates project from Vue 2 to Vue 3 and we’ve encountered some troubles with lifecycle hooks. Some external plugins (compatible with Vue 3) have troubles with mounting / unmounting. We didn’t change the way we call them in our project. It seems that Vue 3 mounted() is slightly different than Vue 2 version. It looks that in Vue 3 mounted() starts before DOM is completely loaded and it causes errors - plugins try to initialize in DOM nodes that don’t exist yet - but we initialize plugins in mounted() hook, so DOM should be already accessible. Is there any difference between Vue 2 mounted() and Vue 3 mounted()?
If it matters, these are plugins that make us problems: chart.js, TinyMCEditor.

Not really a Vue3 issue. It can happen in Vue2 if you have any children components or alike. Please consider using nextTick to be sure that everything is already mounted. Check on the given plugins' issues too, might be specific to those or might have people that faced that issue already.
